# AWS Glue create new column from two existing columns with first value that is not null

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

I have received a request for an AWS Glue Job. We have two columns, `goal_name` and `description` in each record. The request is to create a new column that would be filled by `description` if that record has `description` or `goal_name` if that record doesn't have `description`.

I'm new to AWS Glue so I have no idea how to accomplish something like this. I currently have the following in Glue script:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
## @type: DataSource
## @args: [database = "pixel_data", table_name = "pixel_data_nicheresearch_internal", transformation_ctx = "datasource0"]
## @return: datasource0
## @inputs: []
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "pixel_data", table_name = "pixel_data_nicheresearch_internal", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
## @type: ApplyMapping
## @args: [mapping = [("conv_dttm", "string", "conv_dttm", "string"), ("imp_click_dttm", "string", "imp_click_dttm", "string"), ("cid", "string", "cid", "string"), ("imp_click_campaign_id", "long", "imp_click_campaign_id", "long"), ("campaign_name", "string", "campaign_name", "string"), ("imp_click_partner_id", "long", "imp_click_partner_id", "long"), ("partner_name", "string", "partner_name", "string"), ("imp_click_placement_id", "long", "imp_click_placement_id", "long"), ("placement_name", "string", "placement_name", "string"), ("custom_reference_id", "string", "custom_reference_id", "string"), ("imp_click_creative_id", "string", "imp_click_creative_id", "string"), ("goal_name", "string", "goal_name", "string"), ("description", "string", "description", "string"), ("conversion_type", "string", "conversion_type", "string"), ("conv_ip_address", "string", "conv_ip_address", "string"), ("conv_user_agent", "string", "conv_user_agent", "string"), ("custom_var_1", "string", "custom_var_1", "string"), ("custom_var_2", "string", "custom_var_2", "string"), ("custom_var_3", "string", "custom_var_3", "string"), ("custom_var_4", "string", "custom_var_4", "string"), ("conv_revenue", "double", "conv_revenue", "double"), ("idfa", "string", "idfa", "string"), ("sec_diff_utc", "long", "sec_diff_utc", "long"), ("deterministic_match", "long", "deterministic_match", "long"), ("high_probabilistic_match", "long", "high_probabilistic_match", "long"), ("probabilitstic_match", "long", "probabilitstic_match", "long"), ("ip_match", "long", "ip_match", "long"), ("conv_device_type", "string", "conv_device_type", "string"), ("placement_platform", "string", "placement_platform", "string"), ("hhid_match", "long", "hhid_match", "long"), ("click_custom_var_1", "string", "click_custom_var_1", "string"), ("click_custom_var_2", "string", "click_custom_var_2", "string"), ("click_custom_var_3", "string", "click_custom_var_3", "string"), ("click_custom_var_4", "string", "click_custom_var_4", "string"), ("imp_click_custom_var_1", "string", "imp_click_custom_var_1", "string"), ("imp_click_custom_var_2", "string", "imp_click_custom_var_2", "string"), ("imp_click_custom_var_3", "string", "imp_click_custom_var_3", "string"), ("imp_click_custom_var_4", "string", "imp_click_custom_var_4", "string"), ("partition_0", "string", "partition_0", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1"]
## @return: applymapping1
## @inputs: [frame = datasource0]
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("conv_dttm", "string", "conv_dttm", "string"), ("imp_click_dttm", "string", "imp_click_dttm", "string"), ("cid", "string", "cid", "string"), ("imp_click_campaign_id", "long", "imp_click_campaign_id", "long"), ("campaign_name", "string", "campaign_name", "string"), ("imp_click_partner_id", "long", "imp_click_partner_id", "long"), ("partner_name", "string", "partner_name", "string"), ("imp_click_placement_id", "long", "imp_click_placement_id", "long"), ("placement_name", "string", "placement_name", "string"), ("custom_reference_id", "string", "custom_reference_id", "string"), ("imp_click_creative_id", "string", "imp_click_creative_id", "string"), ("goal_name", "string", "goal_name", "string"), ("description", "string", "description", "string"), ("conversion_type", "string", "conversion_type", "string"), ("conv_ip_address", "string", "conv_ip_address", "string"), ("conv_user_agent", "string", "conv_user_agent", "string"), ("custom_var_1", "string", "custom_var_1", "string"), ("custom_var_2", "string", "custom_var_2", "string"), ("custom_var_3", "string", "custom_var_3", "string"), ("custom_var_4", "string", "custom_var_4", "string"), ("conv_revenue", "double", "conv_revenue", "double"), ("idfa", "string", "idfa", "string"), ("sec_diff_utc", "long", "sec_diff_utc", "long"), ("deterministic_match", "long", "deterministic_match", "long"), ("high_probabilistic_match", "long", "high_probabilistic_match", "long"), ("probabilitstic_match", "long", "probabilitstic_match", "long"), ("ip_match", "long", "ip_match", "long"), ("conv_device_type", "string", "conv_device_type", "string"), ("placement_platform", "string", "placement_platform", "string"), ("hhid_match", "long", "hhid_match", "long"), ("click_custom_var_1", "string", "click_custom_var_1", "string"), ("click_custom_var_2", "string", "click_custom_var_2", "string"), ("click_custom_var_3", "string", "click_custom_var_3", "string"), ("click_custom_var_4", "string", "click_custom_var_4", "string"), ("imp_click_custom_var_1", "string", "imp_click_custom_var_1", "string"), ("imp_click_custom_var_2", "string", "imp_click_custom_var_2", "string"), ("imp_click_custom_var_3", "string", "imp_click_custom_var_3", "string"), ("imp_click_custom_var_4", "string", "imp_click_custom_var_4", "string"), ("partition_0", "string", "partition_0", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
## @type: ResolveChoice
## @args: [choice = "make_cols", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2"]
## @return: resolvechoice2
## @inputs: [frame = applymapping1]
resolvechoice2 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = applymapping1, choice = "make_cols", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2")
## @type: DropNullFields
## @args: [transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3"]
## @return: dropnullfields3
## @inputs: [frame = resolvechoice2]
dropnullfields3 = DropNullFields.apply(frame = resolvechoice2, transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3")
## @type: DataSink
## @args: [catalog_connection = "product-analytics-test", connection_options = {"dbtable": "conversions", "database": "pixel_data"}, transformation_ctx = "datasink4"]
## @return: datasink4
## @inputs: [frame = dropnullfields3]
datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = dropnullfields3, catalog_connection = "product-analytics-test", connection_options = {"dbtable": "conversions", "database": "pixel_data"}, transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
job.commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to convert the Glue DynamicFrame to a native Spark DataFrame. Then you can use the [coalesce function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce.html) from Spark.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from awsglue import DynamicFrame
new_data_frame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(dropnullfields3.toDF().withColumn('new_column_name', F.coalesce(F.col('description'), F.col('goal_name'))), glueContext, 'df')
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, when I add that snippet to my code on line 36 (under `dropnullfields3`) I now get a connection refused?

Comment: Never mind, I get the following error: NameError: name 'coalesce' is not defined

Comment: You need to import it. I've edited my answer :)

Comment: Thank you! Is this all I need to add to my code? Do I need to point to `new_data_frame` in `datasink4`?

Comment: Yes, you need to change it to 'datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = new_data_frame, catalog_connection = "product-analytics-test", connection_options = {"dbtable": "conversions", "database": "pixel_data"}, transformation_ctx = "datasink4")'

Comment: Thank you so much for your continued help! I seem to be getting this error now: `TypeError: frame_or_dfc must be DynamicFrame orDynamicFrameCollection. Got <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>`

So I think I need to convert back to a DynamicFrame before inserting into the database.

Comment: Updated my answer again :D

Comment: Thank you for all your help. This works but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be picking anything up in the logic.

Comment: Actually this was due to AWS Glue bookmarking and not running against current data.. Thank you so much!